# Mod-security exception rule for url as parameter

Tags: php, mod-security, mod-security2

I am new to mod security and was able to install it on my servers. However after its installation the website hosted is breaking up. After tracing the issue I was able to figure out that its not allowing me to pass url as a paramater in php code.
eg: xyz.php?url=**http://www.example.com/img/abc.jpg&param2=xyz**
Can there be any exceptions that can be added to modsecurity so that it allows to pass url as paramaters.

Thanking You,

Aazim

Comment: Now I am facing another issue. The above resolution worked for many. Now myajaxcalls.php file contains all the code which we call through browser, so basically its for getting data using javascript ajax calls. And it gives me 403 error due mod security. Also we are not able to get any id for the same in logs. Need a resolution for this one too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server administration, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the mod_security rule Id from the logs then add the directive below to your virtualhost section:

`SecRuleRemoveById`

Example:

`SecRuleRemoveById 950005`

Are you able to view the apache and modsec logs?

Comment: Now I am facing another issue. The above resolution worked for many. Now myajaxcalls.php file contains all the code which we call through browser, so basically its for getting data using javascript ajax calls. And it gives me 403 error due mod security. Also we are not able to get any id for the same in logs. So can you please help with  the same.

Comment: 403 is Forbidden and not caused by mod_security which usually produces 406 error. Check apache error log.

Comment: ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "streq 0" against "TX:MSC_PCRE_LIMITS_EXCEEDED" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] [line "92"] [msg "ModSecurity internal error flagged: TX:MSC_PCRE_LIMITS_EXCEEDED"] [hostname "website.com"] [uri "/myajaxcalls.php"] [unique_id "UO0vggAAAI0AAGOyCUEAAAAD"]

Comment: This is the error I am getting in apache error logs. So do I have to set some kind of rule for modsecurity that will get it working.

Comment: You need to increase limits by adding `SecPcreMatchLimit` directive. Try `SecPcreMatchLimit 1500` for start and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried increasing the limit to 1500 & it did not work. Hence increased the limit till 50000 but it did not help.

Comment: Try this: `SecPcreMatchLimit 150000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22447/discussion-between-aazim-parkar-and-alectmh)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upgrading the modsecurity resolved 90% of the issues. As I am new to mod it was quite difficult for me to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a rule to ignore that particular arg to your vhost should do it

```
SecRule !ARGS:url
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. However the php code was written in such a way that it was generating multiple urls. Hence we couldnt use this option.