# Putting http://www. in URL parameter causes problems

Tags: php, query-string

My original problem is with an affiliate network redirect script which is not working.

At first I thought the culprit was my .htaccess but even when changing to completely other hosting it does not work.

This is the code I have now to test this:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo "Hello world";
exit;
?>
```

I have it as a a file moredirect.php. If I call it like this http://www.kelluvatrusinat.fi/moredirect.php?url=whatever it works.

However, if I try to put an actual URL in the parameter server responds with 404. In another server I get error 500.

This does not work:
http://www.kelluvatrusinat.fi/moredirect.php?url=http://www.google.com

Any ideas?

Comment: could you post the contents of your .htaccess (it still could cause a problem). And also the contents of your apache error log (where the 404 and 500 errors are displayed)

Comment: The problem is triggered by the colon. `http://www.kelluvatrusinat.fi/moredirect.php?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com` doesn't work but `http://www.kelluvatrusinat.fi/moredirect.php?url=http%2f%2fwww.google.com` does. Can you post your `.htaccess` please ?

Comment: I actually emptied up all .htaccess files. They are just empty files. Still getting the 404.

Comment: In error log of the hosting I get:

[Tue Jul 02 07:53:38 2013] [error] [client 202.67.6.11] File does not exist: /home/mannerv/public_html/kelluvatrusinat.fi/403.shtml

Comment: I am now suspecting that this has something to do with server security. I noticed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215419/mod-security-exception-rule-for-url-as-parameter

Maybe there is mod_security blocking passing URL as parameter?